# Timer which runs loops

Tags: node.js

Question has been answered.

Note: Im trying to output this to a webpage i only used console for reference. I have the css code set up.

```
    var r_text = ['Hi', 'Go', 'No'];
function countdown() {

    var count = 20;
    var timerId = setInterval(function() {
        count--;
        console.log(count);

        if(count == 0) {
            console.log(r_text[Math.floor( Math.random() * r_text.length )]);
            count = 20;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
countdown();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var r_text = ['Hi', 'Go', 'No'],
    textProp = 'textContent' in document.createElement('div') ?
               'textContent' :
               'innerText',
    //update this ID selector to match an element in the page:
    elementToReceiveWord = document.getElementById('WORD'),
    seconds = 20; //timer in seconds

function countdown() {
    var count = seconds;
    var timerId = setInterval(function() {
        count--;
        console.log(count);

        if(count == 0) {
            var word = r_text[Math.floor( Math.random() * r_text.length )];
            elementToReceiveWord[textProp] = word;
            setTimeout(function() {
                  elementToReceiveWord[textProp] = '';
            }, 5000);
            count = seconds;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
countdown();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rdVS/)

Don't forget to update the `elementToReceiveWord`'s ID selector to select an element in the page.

There were a couple mistakes with your original code:

- `r_randomtext`/`r_text` var name mismatches;
- Not drawing a new random value before showing the texts;
- Wrong length of the array in Math.random() * x;
- Timer was 10s instead of the requested 20s.

Improvements:

- Use literal array syntax (more concise, shorter and interpreter optimization-friendly).
- Inline'd some Math operations.

I've employed a feature detection check for elements' text property as well. All modern browsers support `textContent` which is the W3C standard, I'm using `innerText` as a fallback for old IE. Chrome supports both properties, Firefox only supports `textContent`, and IE<9 does not support `textContent` (hence the `innerText` fallback).

If you don't care about old IE, you can remove that check and simply use `element.textContent = ...` instead.

Comment: this doesnt disappear text after 5 seconds though

Comment: Well yes, as long as you're running in the console it won't disappear. Maybe you want to print it to a web page?

Comment: yes im printing to a web page! I have the css code set up, i just cant get the javascript to print to it

Comment: so on the webpage based on the code you producded would this print it in html:

<div id="x" class="ID">
    <p id="ID">  0 </p>
    </div>
?

Comment: refactored my code a bit and added a demo. I've used an `id="WORD"` for the demo now, you can use any valid ID (combination of word, number and underline/hyphen) as long as the HTML's ID matches the `getElementById`'s argument.

Comment: If you need to show the counter in the page you can do something similar with IDs. I can add that to the example if you'd like.